# how to set default select value with angular2 reactive forms?

Tags: html, angular

I have this reactive form:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" novalidate>
  <div *ngIf="myForm.get('id').value === 'Person'">
   <div formGroupName="person">
      <select class="form-control" formControlName="name"> 
        <option selected="selected">XX</option>  //Cannot make this work      
        <option *ngFor="let n of names" [value]="n">{{n}}</option>
      </select>
    <label>Select a name</label>
   </div>
  </div>
    // etc
</form>
```

I cannot set a default selected value to my select tag, why it doesnt work?

Comment: You should put `selected` like this `<option selected>XX</option> `

Comment: tried it and not work

Answer (score 4):

You can set value as empty:

```
<option value="">XX</option>
```

and when building your form, just set default value to empty:

```
name: ['']
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/ttkHhXOP6r3nJcWQ7cP1?p=preview)**

Answer (score 0):

The way to select a value by default is in the component:

```
formControl: FormControl = new FormControl('yourValue');
```

You can also patch a value:

```
formControl.patchValue('anotherValue);
```